# What is the best way to use puppet to update files within a WAR file?

Tags: web, jboss, puppet

We have several web projects that we deliver as .war files and deploy to jboss.  We have a situation where the exact same "war"/code base is delivered to multiple environments with each environment requiring different auth-constraints to be defined in the web.xml.  What is the best way/best practice on delivering these different configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

- supply specific builds for each environment
- deploy the same build everywhere and use Puppet or similar tools to manage specific `web.xml` content per environment

Which is cleaner and/or more easy to implement depends on your existing work flows. There may be other alternatives as well.